# Inner joins multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

```
TableA:
+------+------+---------+
| A_Id | B_Id | AValue  |
+------+------+---------+

TableB:
+------+------+------+
| B_Id | A_Id | C_Id |
+------+------+------+

TableC:
+------+------+------+---------+
| C_Id | B_Id | D_Id | CValue  |
+------+------+------+---------+

TableD:
+------+---------+
| D_Id | DValue  |
+------+---------+

SELECT AValue, CValue, Dvalue
FROM TableA 
inner JOIN TableB
    ON TableA.A_Id = TableB.A_Id
inner JOIN TableC
    ON TableB.B_Id=TableC.B_Id;
inner JOIN TableD
    ON TableC.D_Id=TableD.D_Id;
```

However this is not giving the DValue column that I need but only AValue and CValue columns. I need all three columns. How would I got about doing this?

Comment: Your query looks ok.

Comment: Why does `TableB` have a `C_Id` and `TableC` have a `D_Id`? This seems to be wrong.

Comment: Are you sure there is only one 'DValue' and not some ambiguous other column named that?

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  Also a SQL Fiddle can be very helpful.

Comment: If there is a corresponding `DValue` in `TableD` then it will be displayed. Otherwise the INNER JOIN will return no row at all. Only a LEFT JOIN could return an `AValue` and a `CValue` but no `DValue`.

Comment: The only way I can think that you'd get the results you've reported are if `DVALUE` is NULL. Could this be the case?

Answer (score 0):

There is something illogical in your columns keys. TableC and TableB contains 3 mapping key... While I don't really know what they represent, some of them are not mapped, maybe you want to try

```
SELECT AValue, CValue, Dvalue
FROM TableA 
inner JOIN TableB using(B_Id)
inner JOIN TableC using(C_Id)
inner JOIN TableD using(D_Id)
```

Comment: @BobJarvis Re-read the OP's query and you will notice that C_Id is never used.

Comment: @ JeanFrançoisSavard - I'm not sure that really matters (although OP's query *could* be incorrect). Based on OP's query it appears that A and B are one-to-many, B and C are one-to-many, and D and C are one-to-many (that is - one row in D is related to many rows in C). C_ID is not used in these relationships. But I still haven't had my coffee (but the critters in the barn are fed, by God! :-) and so I may not yet be thinking straight. :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis I agree, however I'm just trying to show OP a different query that would also works.. As his initial query seemed OK to me.. Anyway, let just wait and see if OP gives any feedback while we drink our coffee :)